# At-commands show if there's no load or bad signal in sending sms VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, at-command

Hi I already send sms by at-commands.but if my modem doesn't have a load by program still sending even there's no load.

this is my code

```
    Dim sql As New MySqlDataAdapter("select StudentID, StudentName,StudentContact, DueDate  FROM issue inner join student on student.StudentID = issue.Student  ", conn)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    sql.Fill(ds, 0)
    For i As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        Dim wholenum As String
        Dim wholesms As String
        wholenum = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(2).ToString
        wholesms = "Hello " & ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(1).ToString & ",  ibalik muna libro namen. Due Date mo " & ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(3).ToString & " PUTA Balik muna!!"

        If SerialPort1.IsOpen Then
            Try
                With SerialPort1
                    .Write("AT" & vbCrLf)
                    .Write("AT+CMGF=1" & vbCrLf)
                    .Write("AT+CMGS=" & Chr(34) & wholenum & Chr(34) & vbCrLf)
                    .Write(wholesms & Chr(26))

                    MsgBox(" SEND")

                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(7000)
                    'update one 

                End With

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("No LOAD")
            End Try

        Else
            MsgBox("awwtsu")
        End If
```

Comment: "even there's no load" does not make sense. (I realise you're probably not a native English speaker, but …)

Comment: Do you mean that your device is not attached to sp or what ?

Comment: sp? my device is attached. i'm trying to do if my device is out/lack of load then the program will show that my device is no load... Sorry in my english, i'm not a native english speaker